Traceroute vulnerability 22.04
Trying to look at patching this: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6478-1
Am I right in assuming this patch is only available to those with a Pro contract on the server? https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6478-1#community
If I look at the installed version, it shows traceroute/jammy,now 1:2.1.0-2 amd64 [installed] but it looks like the patched version should have ~esm1 at the end..
Am I going mad? Is it patched already? Or am I unable to patch it without Pro?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Pro is free for up to 5 machines for personal use. So no need not to use it.

Thanks, but this isn't for personal use.

The updated/mitigated application is freely available upstream, just not in .deb format.

A patch was seemingly not released by upstream, so I hesitate to use the term "patched" lest folks get confused.

The package itself is not part of a stock install of Ubuntu. Most users never need it nor install it, and so are unaffected.

Packages that are included with a stock install of Ubuntu are in the main pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. main package security updates are available to everybody. Pro is for packages in the universe pocket, not main.

Any member of the community with the requisite skills can update the package, and hand it to a MOTU for upload. Then all non-Pro users get it immediately, too.
Pro customers will get the mitigated application in .deb format immediately. A convenience like most Pro services.
Non-LTS users will get the updated/mitigated package in the next release of Ubuntu (24.10).
